# Gaussian distribution probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, binomial-distribution

I am using Gaussian distribution to solve the below question. By applying 
below formula, I could find the answer to the first question as 0.

Does this mean that the probability of getting 185 pounds man is zero?
Also How to solve the second question using this formula and explain when to use Gaussian distribution and its meaning and how different it is from Binomial Distribution.

$$
f(x,μ,σ)= \large f(x,\mu , \sigma )=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\; e^{\frac{-(x- \mu)^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}
$$

1. Assume the average weight of an American adult male is 180 pounds
   with a standard deviation of 34 pounds. The distribution of weights
   follows a normal distribution. What is the probability that a man
   weighs exactly 185 pounds?
2. Like in the previous question, assume the average weight of an
   American adult male is 180 pounds with a standard deviation of 34
   pounds. The distribution of weights follows a normal distribution.
   What is the probability that a man weighs somewhere between 120 and
   155 pounds?

Comment: Please show some work so people now where you are confused. Have you answered the first question yet? Note, you will want to use a CDF table for a standard normal distribution to compute (2), the integral cannot (easily) be evaluated directly.

Comment: Your error is in assuming that weight is measured infinitely accurately, that is, with an infinite number of digits of precision.  That clearly is not the case.  Weights are measured to the nearest pound.  As such, you answer to 1. is incorrect.

Comment: For the first question, I used x = 185 and mean as 180 and standard deviation as 34. Applying in the formula gives 0 in the calculator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly, you need to brush up on what a PDF (Probability Density Function) means.
$P(X = 185) = 0$ but not in the way that you think. Probabilities from a PDF are calculated through an integral. Area under the curve gives us what the probability is for $x$ to be in that range.

Hence ,
$P(X = 185) = \int_{185}^{185}f(x,\mu, \sigma)dx = 0$.

Similarly, you can find the $P(120<X<155) = \int_{120}^{155}f(x,\mu, \sigma)dx$

One more thing to note is that you cannot calculate this integral directly. You will need online calculators to find the answer to that.

Comment: Could you please provide the url for calculating this integral? I am very blank to maths, don't even know what keyword to use for searching it.

Comment: @Franva [Normal Distribution Probability calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the answer and the markdown.

Answer (score 0):

for the first question, the probability will be zero because weight is a continuous variable, and integrating between itself will result in zero when subtracting.
for the second question:
z = (x - μ)/σ
z<sub>1</sub> = (155 - 180)/34 = -0.7353
z<sub>2</sub> = (120 - 180)/34 = -1.7647
use a z score table to look up the prabability for each value of z you can find one online on http://www.z-table.com?
you'll find p<sub>1</sub> = 0.2327 and p<sub>2</sub> = 0.0392
probability is equal to p1-p2 = 0.1935

Answer (score 0):

2. Assume the average weight of an American adult male is 180 pounds with a standard deviation of 34 pounds. The distribution of weights follows a normal distribution. What is the probability that a man weighs somewhere between 120 and 155 pounds?

To find P of weight is between 120 and 155 given average weight of 180...

For weight = 120
P(120|180) = 120 / 180 = 0.6667

For weight = 155
P(155|180) = 155 / 180 = 0.8611

Therefore to find P of weight to be between 120 and 155 given 180, we simply do

P(155|180) - P(120|180) = 0.8611 - 0.6667

Therefore $P = 0.1944$
Answer!

Comment: Er, this doesn't take in the variance into consideration at all does it? Therefore how is this a reliable method in ANY circumstance?